# C# Generic IEnumerable

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

I'm learning about the iterator pattern under the hood so eventually I can use it in some classes. Here's a test class:

```
public class MyGenericCollection : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private int[] _data = { 1, 2, 3 };

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (int i in _data)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I'm confused on the `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` section. In the code tests that I've ran, it's never referenced or used, but I have to have it to implement the generic `IEnumerable`.

I do understand that `IEnumerable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerator`, so that I have to implement both.

Outside of that I'm confused when the non-generic interface is ever used. In debugging it's never entered. Can anyone help  me understand?

Comment: Explicit interface implementations are only used when the reference type is the interface they implement. If you would do `IEnumerable x = new myGenericCollection()` you would see it run.

Comment: It is the .NET 1.0 tax.  The framework would look very different if 1.0 never happened.  But everybody has to start *somewhere* and improvements can't break all existing programs.

Comment: @ZoharPeled indeed, this was the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm confused on the IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() section. In the code tests that I've ran, it's never referenced or used, but I have to have it to implement the generic IEnumerable.

It would be used by anything that used your type as just an `IEnumerable`. For example:

```
IEnumerable collection = new MyGenericCollection();
// This will call the GetEnumerator method in the non-generic interface
foreach (object value in collection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

There are just a few LINQ methods that would call it, too: `Cast` and `OfType`:

```
var castCollection = new MyGenericCollection().OfType<int>();
```

Comment: That makes sense. I did not instantiate my MyGenericCollection object as an IEnumerable object, but instead just a MyGenericCollection object. I think this used the generic GetEnumerator() by default.

Oddly enough that you would respond to my question. I am looking forward to C# in Depth (4th edition) which appears to be releasing on Jan 30th which apparently you're the author of. I just wish it was being released a little sooner.

Anyways, I think the answer is clear. Thanks.